# Implementing Discrete Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-analysis

I am trying to implement Discrete Fourier Transform (by definition, in quadratic time).

I wrote this http://jsfiddle.net/uunsm/12/

My result function really goes through discrete points, but it is too "wavy".

When I inserted a sine wave:

```
var nums = [0.000, 0.707, 1.000, 0.707, 0.000, -0.707, -1.000, -0.707]
```

I was expecting to get a smooth sine, but again, there are too many "waves". Am I doing anything wrong?

BTW. I found this implementation http://home.fuse.net/clymer/graphs/dft.html
which is much smoother. Is it still Fourier transform? Where can I find any info about that algorithm?

Comment: This is more related to programming I guess. Now what is the question? errors in your code? or if your code is correct?

Comment: I wanted to know if it is the correct behavior, or if I have any errors.

Comment: The behavior that you are seeing is correct.  It is called Gibbs Phenomenon (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon).  It is a natural artifact of trying to represent a non-continuous function (i.e. step) with a set of continuous functions (i.e. sinusoids).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the expected behavior. In your first example, where `var nums = [2, 2, 2, 2,   -2, -2, -2, -2];`, you're essentially trying to replicate a square wave with a series of sines and cosines. You cannot do that with so few terms; in fact, you cannot eliminate the waviness, only make it arbitrarily close (and then you have ringing phenomena, etc).

With your example above, you're trying to represent one low-frequency oscillation with a sum of several higher frequency oscillations. Again, you cannot do that perfectly, so you will get some waviness.

If you want a nice smooth wave, your data has to change with the same frequency as your components. Try this and see what happens.

`var nums = [2, -2, 2, -2,   2, -2, 2, -2];`

Comment: Thakn you very much! I thought that it is expected, but I was not sure. BTW. I added another link to my question, can you tell me something about it?

Comment: @IvanKuckir Yes, this is essentially a Fourier series approximation. However, notice how the coefficients are conditioned by examining the output: every term is zero, except the term that corresponds to $\sin x$. If you view the source of that site, you can see how the coefficients are conditioned to achieve such a condition. The algorithm there is essentially the same as yours, with some additional steps outside the initial loop. Also, notice that code loops over $0 \le i \le n/2$.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer, I have accepted it :) sorry it took me nine years.